# Mathematica performs insufficient or too slow or too memory consuming simplification

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Using Mathematica 10,

```
Simplify[Sqrt[Sin[x]^6 ((a^2 + r[]^2)^2 - 
  a^2 (q^2 + a^2 - 2 m r[] + r[]^2) Sin[x]^2)^2]/((a^2 + 
  a^2 Cos[2 x] + 2 r[]^2)^2 (-a^2 q^2 + a^4 + 
  2 m a^2 r[] + 3 a^2 r[]^2 + 2 r[]^4 + a^2 Cos[2 x] (q^2 + a^2 - 2 m r[] + r[]^2))),
 Assumptions -> {(a^2 + r[]^2)^2 - a^2 (q^2 + a^2 - 2 m r[] + 
    r[]^2) Sin[x]^2 > 0}]
```

yields the weird expression:
$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{\sin ^3(x)}{2 \left(a^2 \cos (2 x)+a^2+2r()^2\right)^2} & \sin (x)\geq 0 \\
 -\frac{\sin ^3(x)}{2 \left(a^2 \cos (2 x)+a^2+2r()^2\right)^2} & \text{True} \\
\end{cases}.$$ 
If I add the assumption $0 \leq x \leq \pi$, then the result becomes:
$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{\sin ^3(x)}{2 \left(a^2 \cos (2 x)+a^2+2r()^2\right)^2} & a^2 (a^2+q^2 -2 m r() +r^2) \sin^2(x)\leq (a^2 + r()^2)^2\\
 -\frac{\sin ^3(x)}{2 \left(a^2 \cos (2 x)+a^2+2r()^2\right)^2} & \text{True} \\
\end{cases},$$ in which the first conditional is actually the first assumption! The correct result is of course the first without the extra conditional.

What does the "True" conditional mean? Why is the second result still not sufficiently simplified?

### Another example (2):

```
Simplify[Conjugate[a + I Cos[θ] r], Assumptions -> {a > 0, θ > 0, r > 0}]
```

yields `Conjugate[a + I r Cos[θ]]`. If I attempt simplification of each part in the sum, the result is the expected one!

`Simplify` seems to be a extremely sensitive to input. Is there any advice to work around these issues?

### Another example (3):

Is it possible to make `FullSimplify` apply only to expressions that include `Conjugate`, so that the expression can be simplified quickly? I have a long expression and only simplification of the `Conjugate` is necessary; `FullSimplify` on the full expression takes more than an hour. Any ideas?

**Solution**
The fastest way (mere seconds) I could find to simplify an expression enclosed in `Conjugate` is to define the expression as `Map[Simplify[Conjugate[#]]&, expr,{-1}]`. This has the drawback that the simplified `Conjugate` is mapped only on "objects that have no subparts", according to the documentation, which suits my purpose fine at the moment.

### Another example (4):

When trying to simplify a very long expression, `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` cache intermediate results of the simplification in order to speed up the process, but this has certain disadvantages:

1. Long expressions tend to create extremely big caches, which is apparent as the memory size of the kernel reaches many GB and is never released after the simplification is aborted.
2. The result changes depending on the cache created earlier, which reduces the determinism of the process.
3. The cache created earlier may cause next simplifications to last too long for various reasons.

Is there a way to disable or control the cache created by `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`?

Comment: "What does the `True` conditional mean?" - it's what we often refer to as the "otherwise" case for piecewise-defined functions.

Comment: Doesn't this explanation assume a specific order of reading the result? Is this standard behaviour in Mathematica?

Comment: Sometimes, *Mathematica* finds it convenient to return piecewise results; in your case, the "specific order" seems to be quite apparent: "first result if the first condition is met, and the second result otherwise".

Comment: Actually, "true" cannot mean "otherwise", because in the second conditional of the second result this explanation is wrong!

Comment: According to the documentation for `Piecewise`, the conditions are evaluated **in order**, until one evaluates to `True`; the value displayed with the condition `True` is in fact the default value *`val`* (where *`val`* is the term in the docs).  (The last value displayed will always be the default and be accompanied by `True`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 According to the documentation, the default for `val` is `0`, which is not the case here. The second conditional of the second result is only valid in the case $\sin(x)<0$ and $a^2(a^2+q^2−2mr()+r^2)\sin^2(x)\leq (a^2+r()^2)^2$, which is not the result Mathematica returns!

Comment: I was responding to your query, "Doesn't this explanation assume a specific order of reading the result?"  The answer is yes.  I don't know what you mean to imply by citing "the default for `val` is 0."  In both cases above, a specific expression is supplied for `val.` The docs describe `val` thus: "`Piecewise` uses default value `val` if none of the `Subscript[cond, i]` apply." To make things confusing, it goes on to indicate the "default for `val`" -- i.e. the default for the default.  (I was not addressing your principal question.  Sorry for the confusion.)

Comment: For future reference: I had to work around this by creating a list, selecting the appropriate results with `Part`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. @MichaelE2, Is there a way to see what parts of `Piecewise` I need to access in order to form the list? I'm asking because via trial and error I got `y[[2,1,1,1]]` for the first part of the second element of a list with `Piecewise` results and `y[[3,2]]` for the second part of the third element.

Comment: @auxsvr Use `InputForm` or `FullForm` to see enough of the internal form of something that you can use `Part` or `Extract` on it.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To address your practical examples:

For the first question, you can just simplify in an additional step:

```
Simplify[
  Sqrt[Sin[x]^6 ((a^2 + r[]^2)^2 - 
       a^2 (q^2 + a^2 - 2 m r[] + r[]^2) Sin[x]^2)^2]/((a^2 + 
       a^2 Cos[2 x] + 2 r[]^2)^2 (-a^2 q^2 + a^4 + 2 m a^2 r[] + 
      3 a^2 r[]^2 + 2 r[]^4 + 
      a^2 Cos[2 x] (q^2 + a^2 - 2 m r[] + r[]^2))), 
  (a^2 + r[]^2)^2 - a^2 (q^2 + a^2 - 2 m r[] + r[]^2) Sin[x]^2 > 0
];

Simplify[%, 0 <= x <= π]

(* Sin[x]^3/(2 (a^2 + a^2 Cos[2 x] + 2 r[]^2)^2) *)
```

For the second question, you can use `FullSimplify`

```
FullSimplify[Conjugate[a + I Cos[θ] r], Assumptions -> {a > 0, θ > 0, r > 0}]

(* a - I r Cos[θ] *)
```

or `ComplexExpand`, which is usually more efficient for this kind of simplification:

```
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[a + I Cos[θ] r]]
(* a - I r Cos[θ] *)
```

For the third question, if you want to simplify just the `Conjugate` expressions, you can do

```
expr /. c_Conjguate :> FullSimplify[c]
```

You could also create more sophisticated rules based on the specific form of the expression that you're trying to simplify.

Comment: The problem with your answer to the first question is that it is very unreliable; `Simplify` fails to work with the same condition against a different expression in many cases. The most reliable way I've found so far is to use a rule to replace the expression in the condition with a variable `x`, `Simplify` with respect to `x` satisfying certain conditions, then replace `x` with the original expression.

Comment: `ComplexExpand` does not work in my case, probably because certain variables have special properties in xAct. It throws error messages such as "$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 Exceeded". `FullSimplify` works, though. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer for the third question does not work if the expression wrapped in `Conjugate` is too long, which is the case I was stuck with. I'm sorry if I didn't explain this clearly.