# Simplest identity that cannot be proved by FullSimplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, expression-manipulation

Apparently, `FullSimplify` is not able to prove all true identities, but usually it does pretty well when it comes to elementary functions. I'd like to know what are the simplest (or near simplest) examples that cannot be handled by it, and what is so special about them that makes them difficult?

What true simple identities containing only elementary functions and no variables you encountered that cannot be proved by `FullSimplify`?

My examples:

```
FullSimplify[(1 + √2)^√2 == (3 + √8)^(1/√2)]

FullSimplify[160 ArcTan[2]^2 + 32 ArcTan[3]^2 - 48 ArcTan[7]^2 == 15 π^2]

FullSimplify[ArcCsch[2]^2 + (ArcSinh[2]/3 + Log[2]) Log[√5 - 1] == Log[2]^2]
```

Comment: Use `Reduce` with arbitrary precision: `15 Pi^2 - 160 ArcTan[2]^2 - 32 ArcTan[3]^2 + 48 ArcTan[7]^2 == 0 // Reduce[#, WorkingPrecision -> 15] &` evaluates to `True`

Comment: I'm not sure of any other of these types of identities off the top of my head, but I know Mma in general has trouble denesting radicals. Though this is only simple if you assume you know Galois theory (see [here](https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/focs/1989/1982/00/063496.pdf)).

Comment: p.s.`PossibleZeroQ[
  15 π^2 - 160 ArcTan[2]^2 - 32 ArcTan[3]^2 + 48 ArcTan[7]^2]` returns `True`, but a message is thrown and it's only verified numerically it looks like.

Comment: What is the measure of complexity that should be used to establish this "exact lower bound"? Unless you supply this in computable form, your question can not be answered.

Comment: @BobHanlon The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) says: "Using `WorkingPrecision->100` enables `Reduce` to find a solution, but it may be incorrect". So, basically, a use of this option waives any guarantees of mathematical correctness, and switches to approximate numeric methods.

Comment: @m_goldberg We could say that it's measured by the default complexity function used by `FullSimplify`, but I am not really looking for the exact minimum. I just want to see what simple patterns are not handled by `FullSimplify`.

Comment: @ChipHurst I believe any true identity in radicals can be reliably converted to `True` by `RootReduce`. It is not always done by `FullSimplify` though.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Yes, only if you pass both nested and unnested. If you just pass the nested version, you're usually stuck. e.g. `CubeRoot[CubeRoot[2] - 1]`.

Comment: `FullSimplify` takes too long to simplify a long expression enclosed in `Conjugate`. Your question is very interesting, because I've found out that `FullSimplify` and `Simplify` are extremely sensitive to input and very often require a special way of writing the expressions in order to work well or at all; see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91528/mathematica-performs-insufficient-or-too-slow-simplification) for more details.

Comment: This is an interesting question and should be reopened.

Comment: To summarize: you're looking for examples of constant identities that involve only elementary functions, but cannot be dealt with by `FullSimplify[]`?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Yes